# C# memory leakage while using postgresql ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, postgresql, memory-leaks, npgsql

Using Postgresql under C# I got memory leakage.  Is there simple way to avoid it?  (google told me to replace the Postgres with another DB. Which is impossible, I have to connect to existing system).

to reproduce the memory-leak :

C# (dot net 4) run lots of update queries as shown in the next code:

```
using Npgsql;
```

.
.
.

```
class dbCommector
{
    private Object lockerObj = new object();
    private NpgsqlConnection conn = null;

    public dbCommector()
    {
        conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;User Id=user;" +
                                        "Password=password;Database=demo;");
        conn.Open();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    public void NoAnsExecute(String query)
    {
        lock (lockerObj)
        {
            using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                //If I put here "return", no leakage.
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//Create one object from this class

```
dbCommector myConnector = new dbCommector();
```

//then calling a lot of the next query or alike:

```
myConnector,NoAnsExecute ("update table set value=0 where id=1");
```

Comment: What makes you think that you've got a memory leak here? Any observations?

Comment: Running the program for 110 minutes, by the windows task manager, memory usage increased from 40 to 300.   with the "return" command before the ExecuteNonQuery, memory usage is stable at 40.  leaving program to run all the night, I've got exception of "out of memory".  (no such exception when the "return" is there).

Comment: Have you seen/tried this: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q491917/outofmemoryexception-with-npgsql

Comment: thanks @dnickless but this had no effect.  I'm using version 2.2.3 that by the developers should fix this bug.  https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/415

Comment: See github: https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/216. My attempts at reproducing the leak with 3.2.5 have failed.

Comment: @ShayRojansky , thanks for your help.  I've send to the right repository a full code with results of 10 hours test, and full code to reproduce.https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1650